# SQL select multiple values in single column into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to select from a *single* table with a simple set of data, but somehow transpose the type column into multiple columns using a simple select statement.

An example of the data I'm working with:

| id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/06/01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022/06/01 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022/06/01 | 3 |
| 4 | 2022/06/01 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022/06/01 | 2 |
| 6 | 2022/06/01 | 3 |

What I am hoping to achieve, using SQL only:

| date_format(%y-%m-%d) | SMS | Email | Online |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/06/01 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `1` means SMS, `2` means Email, and `3` means Online, then the query can look like:

```
select
  date,
  sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as sms,
  sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as email,
  sum(case when type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as online
from t
group by date
```

Comment: A colleague and I tried so many ways to accomplish this. Thank you so much, The Impaler!!!!